# Run Query within Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to run this query every time my client uploads a product, so how do I run this query within Wordpress? I want to tie it to an action in the functions.php

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
    JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id
    SET wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'no'
    WHERE (wp_posts.post_title = '4x6' AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_virtual')
```

Comment: How are you uploading product? are u using woocommerce?

Comment: I am but its also using a bulk image uploader which converts to products.

Comment: Please check http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post and http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/129734/woocommerce-wp-insert-post-action-firing-on-every-save

Comment: Does these products get published automatically?

Comment: They do yes. i just need to be able to run this query in the functions.php

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your functions.php:

```
function on_product_publish( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {

    global $post;

    if ( 'publish' !== $new_status or 'publish' === $old_status ) return;

    $wpdb->query("UPDATE wp_postmeta
    JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id
    SET wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'no'
    WHERE (wp_posts.post_title = '4x6' AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_virtual')");

}

add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'on_product_publish', 10, 3 );
```